# How can I temporarily change title of contents of subsection formatting using titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

I have a common document type (grant application) which expects listed aims, usually enumerated as Aim 1, Aim 2, etc. In the MWE below, an `article` class works fine to format the subsection headings appropriately within the document, but I'm having trouble with the TOC. I'm changing `\thesubsection` and using `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package in anticipation of using the `titletoc` package to change the toc formatting of entries from within a defined `aims` environment.  I want the aims to be listed in the TOC as Aim 1, Aim 2, etc.

What I'm running into:

1. The `\titlecontents` settings I set as part of the `aims` environment appears to persist *after* the end of the environment.  This is different from the `\titleformat` settings, which are local.
2. Unlike the `\titleformat` settings in the `titlesec` package, the default `\titlecontents` in `titletoc` are not listed in the documentation, so my attempt to alter the default settings is trial and error (at this point, all error, since I can't get it working).  The `titlesec` examples are invaluable; are there similar examples for `titletoc`?

MWE follows

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage {blindtext}
\usepackage {titlesec}
\usepackage {titletoc}

\newenvironment {aims} {
  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{{\arabic{subsection}}}
  \titleformat{\subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{Aim
    \thesubsection}{1em}{}
  % example from titletoc docs to show that \titlecontents
  % changes persist outside the group
  \titlecontents{subsection} [3.8em]
  {}{\contentslabel{5em}}{\hspace*{-5em} Aim }
  {\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
}{}
\title {A document}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section {Introduction}
\blindtext
\begin {aims}
  \section {Aims}
  \subsection {This is an aim}
  \blindtext
  \subsection {This is another aim}
  \blindtext
\end {aims}
\section {Details}
\blindtext
\subsection {Some more details}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remember that the ToC is set at the beginning of the document (outside your `aims` environment). So, of course, modifying `\titlecontents` would have an effect outside the `aims` environment. Why not create a different macro for your aims so that you can treat them differently in the ToC?

Comment: @Werner, thanks.  I was initially headed down that path, but for some reason (my memory is fuzzy here) changed my mind.  I suppose it's because I went this way that I was longing for some examples of the default `\titlecontents` that I could slot in at the closing of the `aims` environment.  Even if I created a different macro for aims, rather than temporarily hijacking the `\subsection` formatting, I'd still use the examples if I had them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a mild implementation of `\aims` that duplicates the behaviour of `\subsection` from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage {blindtext}% http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext

\makeatletter
% Taken from article.cls's \subsection and introduced it as \aim
\newcounter{aim}
\renewcommand{\theaim}{\arabic{aim}}
\newcommand\aim{\@startsection{aim}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries \hspace*{-\parindent}Aim~}}
\newcommand{\l@aim}{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand{\aimmark}[1]{}% You don't need any header marks for aims
\makeatother

\title {A document}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section {Introduction}
\blindtext

\section {Aims}
\aim {This is an aim}
\blindtext
\aim {This is another aim}
\blindtext

\section {Details}
\blindtext
\subsection {Some more details}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Using `\aim` instead of `\subsection` seems more intuitive. Of course, it would also be possible for format the "Aim" headings differently, if needed; both in the text/document, as well as in the ToC. I've just used the default `\subsection` style (which is `\dottedtocline`, at depths equivalent to `\subsection`).